# Symfony security access control list, url witht uuid placeholder

Tags: php, symfony

how can I tell that I want url for example like `/users/{id}/confirm` to be publically available????
I tried with

```
- { path: ^/users/{id}/confirm, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
```

and syntax is incorrect, also I tried to cover url with quotes and getting 404 response.

Third try:

```
- { path: ^/users/\[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-1[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}/confirm, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
```

yaml incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by using route name instead of path. Like this:

```
- { attributes: {'_route': 'confirmEmail'}, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#config/packages/security.yaml
    security:
        access_control:
            - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
            - { path: ^/users, roles: ROLE_USER}
            - { path: ^/register, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
```

And in your controller, you can use annotations or attributes restrictions :

```
#[IsGranted('ROLE_USER', statusCode: 403, message: 'Please to login..')]
#[Route('/users/{id}', name: 'name_of_..')]
```

More infos : https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html#2-access-enforcement

Maybe to try with differents roles in your restriction attributes/annotations

Comment: that I know but I want all user endpoint to be private except this particular one `/users/{id}/confirm`, well if it's not possible I can make it like `/confirm?id=`

Comment: found ` - { attributes: {'_route': 'admin'}, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }` so maybe I can do it by route name, will try

Answer (score 0):

instead of using id placeholder you need to use numeric placeholder

```
// config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/users/\d+$/confirm, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
```

Comment: but my id is UUID not an integer